# Strange difference when running a Python file directly or packed with py2exe

Tags: python

I build an application that, when running on Windows, should use the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming` and `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` directories for different kind of files -- otherwise, while on Linux, it should use only the `$HOME` directory.

Problem: my code treats differently the `shell.SHGetFolderPath()` function, depending on whether I run the .py file directly or packed via py2exe.

I am using this function as a way for the program to 'know' if it's on Windows (or not). When running the .py file directly, everything is as intended. When running the .py file packed via py2exe, the generated .exe file thinks it's a non-Windows system and uses directly the `%USERPROFILE%` directory as `$HOME` for both application data files and user files. Except for this difference, the rest of the program appears to run ok (each variant follows successfully the own different path).

Q1: What could cause that difference ?

Q2: Is there a better way to detect the Windows/non-Windows environment ? I guess I read about the method I am using somewhere here at StackOverflow, but cannot remember/find where exactly.

The code is this (the beginning of it, enough to actually generate the directories) and next is the code I am using for the py2exe build.

The system I am using for the soup is Windows Vista 64bit, with Python 2.7.6 and py2exe 0.6.9, both 32bit (as well as wxPython 2.8.12, 32bit, unicode, if that matters here).

**edit:** I tried the dabhaid's solution and so I found what causes the difference in my code, but not the cause of the difference generated by py2exe. I mean -- in the .exe variant the program now stops with "ImportError: No module named shell", so now it's clear why the program skips the original `try:` statement.

So now comes a third question:

Q3: What should I do about the error "ImportError: No module named shell" ? This does not happen if running the .py program from command line directly.

**edit2:** I think I found an answer for Q3 at [py2exe.org](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/win32com.shell), will try later to understand the possible fix explained there.

**edit3:** The solution given at py2exe.org worked, problem solved on all questions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

appname = "aa app name"
apppath = "pp path name"

import os
import re

# define OS specific paths
# create application directories if not already existing

# edit -- code changed
# was: try:
# next line is new:
if os.name == 'nt':
""" if windows """
  # edit -- in py2exe packed variant only, the next line gives "ImportError: No module named shell"
  from win32com.shell import shellcon, shell
  homedir_appdata = shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_APPDATA, 0, 0)
  homedir_documents = shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_PERSONAL, 0, 0)
# edit -- code changed
# was: except ImportError:
# next line is new:
else:
  """ if non-windows """
  homedir = os.path.expanduser("~")
  homedir_appdata = homedir
  homedir_documents = homedir
  apppath = "." + apppath.lower()

appdata_path = os.path.join(homedir_appdata, apppath)
documents_path = os.path.join(homedir_documents, apppath)

match = re.search(r'\.', apppath)
if not match:
  """ if windows """
  try:
    os.makedirs(appdata_path)
  except OSError:
    if not os.path.isdir(appdata_path):
      raise
try:
  os.makedirs(documents_path)
except OSError:
  if not os.path.isdir(documents_path):
    raise

# define specific file paths and file names

config_filename = appname + ".ini"
config_filename_wpath = os.path.join(appdata_path, config_filename)
user_filename = appname + ".csv"
user_filename_wpath = os.path.join(documents_path, user_filename)

# etc.
```

and

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')
setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {
        'dll_excludes': ['w9xpopen.exe'],
        'dist_dir': 'dist',
        }
    },
    name = "test",
    windows = [
        {
            'script': "test.py",
        },
    ],
    zipfile = None,
    description = "test file",
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your second question, use

```
import os

if os.name == 'nt':
    #do Windows stuff here
elif os.name == 'posix':
    #do Linux stuff here - note OS X shows up as 'posix'
```

To your first question, py2exe can do some strange things, I had issues with py2app before, but I don't have a Windows box to play with to check shell weirdness on.